# Solving two equations with logarithmic terms with NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I want to solve the following set of equations for $M$ and $\epsilon$ :

```
16.93963 == Log[1 + 1.15022 M ϵ]/ϵ
6.6612 == (0.8694/ϵ + M) Log[0.8694/ϵ + M] - (0.8694/ϵ) Log[0.8694/ϵ]
```

I used `NSolve`:

```
 NSolve[
   {6.6612 == (0.8694/ϵ + M) Log[0.8694/ϵ + M] - (0.8694/ϵ) Log[0.8694/ϵ], 
    1/0.1441 == 1/ϵ Log[1 + M ϵ/0.8694 ]}, {ϵ, M}, Reals]
```

It has been running for quite some time now and not yet returning a solution. Is there some clever trick to get the solution for this system of equations?

#### Update

The output came and it was same as the input.

Comment: What a priori knowledge to have that makes you believe there is a real solution to this system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve the first equation for $M$, and plug that in to the RHS of the second equation. You get an expression that, for positive $ϵ$, bottoms out around 85 (with $ϵ$ near $0.02$. In particular, it never gets anywhere near $6.6612$.